# SQL : Join variable table and view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make an `INNER JOIN` between a table variable and a view

```
SELECT 
    T. * 
FROM 
    @mytable AS T, Vw_GetPackageStat.DimensionValueName
From
    dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat 
INNER JOIN 
    T ON (dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat.AttributeValueID = T.AttributeValueID)
```

I have this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: Have you looked at any example syntax? Did it have two `from` clauses?

Comment: I doubt, Is this a valid syntax?

Comment: Compile your code it's syntax error, Remove one "from".

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  T.* ,
        Vw_GetPackageStat.DimensionValueName
FROM    @AllPackage AS T
        INNER JOIN dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat ON ( dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat.AttributeValueID = T.AttributeValueID )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT  T.* ,
        Vw_GetPackageStat.DimensionValueName
FROM    @AllPackage AS T
        INNER JOIN dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat ON  
        Vw_GetPackageStat.AttributeValueID = T.AttributeValueID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were originally trying to do this

```
SELECT T.*
       ,Vw_GetPackageStat.DimensionValueName
    FROM @mytable AS T
       ,Vw_GetPackageStat
    WHERE dbo.Vw_GetPackageStat.AttributeValueID = T.AttributeValueID
```

this is a valid syntax but I would avoid it at all cost. Instead use traditional explicit `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT T.*
       ,v.DimensionValueName
    FROM @mytable AS T
    INNER JOIN Vw_GetPackageStat AS v
        ON T.AttributeValueID = V.AttributeValueID
```